# Truffle - can deploy to ropsten but not mainnet

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment

I am trying to deploy a contract to the mainnet. My truffle.js looks like this:

```
require('babel-register')
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    "live": {
      network_id: 1,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8546
    }
  },
  rpc: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8545
  }
};
```

I have connected to the mainnet in geth (just with `geth` and `geth attach` though I've also tried `geth --rpcport 8546 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1` for example). My blockchain is fully up to date (running `eth.blockNumber` will show I'm at the latest block or close to it).

Running the following command to deploy my contract:

```
truffle migrate --network live
```

Will result in the following error:

> Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

This problem is truffle isn't connecting to the mainnet at all. I've successfully deployed to the ropsten test network using truffle when geth is connected to that, so am not sure why the mainnet isn't working (when deploying to ropsten I have basically the same truffle.js as above except network_id: 3 instead of network_id: 1, and the same command to deploy the contract except with --network ropsten instead of --network live).

Comment: Have you unlocked and funded your default mainnet account?

Comment: Yes, and the account has ether in it as well.

Comment: Can you try with `--rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,admin,personal"` in your command line? (admin, and personal should not be necessary but I don't know what if truffle requires them).

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `netstat -an` showed the port I though I was running the mainnet on (8546 here) wasn't active. Running the mainnet in geth on port 8545 (like the testnet) and changing truffle.js to look at port 8545 allowed truffle to connect to it.